# OS X app on windows 8 able to run?

Tags: objective-c, macos, window

Hello I made an OS X app and i want it also to be useable on Windows(windows8).

Is there a way to let it run on Windows?

It doesn't matter if I have to compile it again with an other compiler as Xcode uses.

The code is written in objective C.

Comment: No, it's not possible. I think this has been asked before.

Comment: @woz Never say never.

Comment: @H2CO3 Once you go Mac, you can't go back.

Comment: @woz I meant, "not possible" is not true.

Comment: It's both.  It's "not possible" in that x86 Binaries from Mac OS X cannot execute in the CLR, but possible in that there are tools that allow you to remain lazy and use ObjC-syntax to compile into an intermediate form the CLR can tolerate

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to recompile it, then you can use [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) to set up a cross-toolchain targeting Windows (this project also comes with the necessary runtime support, such as a port of AppKit).